# I turn into an animal

Tags: riddle, word, anagram

> I am a city that ends in a city
>
> I start with a state and end in a state
>
> Move me around and I turn into an animal

What three consonant word am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Manila

I am a city that ends in a city

> It is a city and ends with **L.A.**

I start with a state and end in a state

> **Ma** (code for U.S. state of Massachussetts) and **La** (code for U.S. state of Louisiana).

Move me around and I turn into an animal

> Manila is an anagram of **animal**